Expo Opening on iOS crashes with Error: xcrun exited with non-zero code: 60 (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=60)
Problem
I want to test/emulate a newly created default React Native App with Expo Go on an emulated iOS device.
However, upon pressing i and opening on iOS an error occurs:

Error: xcrun exited with non-zero code: 60
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=60):
Unable to boot the Simulator.
launchd failed to respond.
Underlying error (domain=com.apple.SimLaunchHostService.RequestError, code=4):
Failed to start launchd_sim: could not bind to session, launchd_sim may have crashed or quit responding

Important Note
Yesterday it worked just fine. I changed nothing in the code or setup at all.
How to reproduce the error
In the Visual Studio Code Terminal press i to open Android Virtual Device emulation with Expo.
i

And the error occurs:

Question
How can this be fixed so that it works properly again?

Try to Delete Xcode Caches.
Click on the top-left Apple Icon and open System Settings. Then:

search for "Storage",
click on "Storage",
wait until the right side loads a "Developer" item
double-click "Developer"
Delete Xcode Caches

Then restart the simulator.
